# Sinon stub undefined with node.js and mocha tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I want to mock a method of ES6 class.

I am importing models module:

```
// test.js
const models = require(path.resolve('./models'));
```

In models folder there is an index.js and it redirects to index.js in user folder while calling models.user:

```
// models/index.js
models.user = user;
```

Then I have a user class in index.js:
    // models/user/index.js

```
class User extends Model {
  // simplified exists - it returns boolean or thows an error
  static async exists(username) {
    if (username) {
      returns true
    } else {
      throw new Error('bad output');
    }
  }
}
```

I want to stub exist(username) method with sinon stub.

I am doing:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const models = require(path.resolve('./models'));

describe.only('generateTokenBehavior()', function() {
    it('should return 200 given valid username and password', function() {
        ...
        const stub = sinon.stub();
        stub(models.user.prototype, 'exists').callsFake(true);
        ...
    });
```

and I am getting an error on the line with stub:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'callsFake' of undefined
```

What is wrong with this code? I was researching this problem on similar stack questions but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that calling the result of *sinon.stub()* as a function returns *undefined*.

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const models = require(path.resolve('./models'));

describe.only('generateTokenBehavior()', function() {
    it('should return 200 given valid username and password', function() {
        ...
        const stub = sinon.stub(models.user.prototype, 'exists').callsFake(true);
        ...
    });
```

---

For reference, the documentation is here:
http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.1/stubs/#properties

I don't blame you for writing it the way you did - the documentation is a bit misleading.